# Why does exposure to a smell for some time reduce the electrical response of receptor neurons in the olfactory system?

Tags: human-biology, perception, neuron

In what way does exposure to a certain smell for some time causes them to loose sensitivity and have a lesser electrical response

Comment: You may find providing a little more research/context will help net more useful answers? For example, is there research that shows reduced olfactoy sensitivity is a peripheral phenomenon occurring at the receptors, as opposed to sensory filtering that happens in the CNS? I'm also curious about time scales. Are you interested in long-term exposure and/or chronic loss of sensitivity or more short-term/transient phenomena, like when you get in a funky smelling car but stop noticing after a few minutes?

Comment: Both, long term exposure as in you cant tell if you smell bad because ur used to ur smell and short term as in u keep smelling a perfume and u stop smelling it for a short period of time

Comment: in what way is that different to any neural adaptation?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_adaptation